# simplexml_load_string => Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed[Error] // passing xml file contents from url to variable

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

it's not a duplicate because i read all other questions and answers and could not solve my problem and mine is a little different

```
$tcmb_gov_tr = file_get_contents("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
      $currency_xml = simplexml_load_string($tcmb_gov_tr);
      $tmp_currency = array();
      if($currency_xml->Currency[0]['Kod']=='USD'){
        $_SESSION['currency']['usd_try']['buying'] = $currency_xml->Currency[0]->ForexBuying[0];
        $_SESSION['currency']['usd_try']['selling'] = $currency_xml->Currency[0]->ForexSelling[0];
      }
```

code works but still throwing

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active
>   file] on line 0

i dont want to get that error what should i do, i get values from xml as array or object, you can suggest anohter method or help me to use that function right

Comment: The fact your error is being thrown from "line 0" implies that it's happening on script shutdown - are you storing the $currency variable in the session?

Comment: no i dont store it in the session

Comment: i dont store $currency directly to session but i store its values in session, and why i dont know but storing its values in session throwing that error, Thank you iainn, if you want, create an answer and i will mark it as right answer.
not storing its values in session solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Simple best solution

```
$_SESSION['currency']['usd_try']['buying'] = (string)$currency_xml->Currency[0]->ForexBuying[0];
```

i find out that it stored as simplexmlelement, when i put (string) before xml element, session variable stores it as string then no errors. (string) calling a xml element to string function.